# Using pretrained weights on specific object detection tasks

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection

Is there a point to using pretrained weights if my object detection task is doesn't involve identifying common images? The yolonet tutorial uses pretrained weights from the imagenet competition but I'm trying to train an object detector to find certain crustal deformation patterns.

Answer (score 0):

There might not be any common high level features between crustal deformation patterns and imagenet training data, but it's quite probable that there are common low level features related to texture, color, edges etc. So pretraining on imagenet **might** boost convergence speed on your model's first layers which are responsible for detecting low level features, and increase the final accuracy of your model.